# React Native - Undefined is not an object (evaluating "iter[Symbol.iterator]")

Tags: react-native

We just sent me a big react native project that I can't open and I can't figure it out why.
I've got the message : "Undefined is not an object (evaluating "Iter[Symbol.iterator]")".
I can't access the app because of it and didn't find any topic that helped me.

Here the package.json :

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "prettier": "prettier --ignore-path .gitignore \"**/*.+(js|jsx|json)\"",
    "format": "npm run prettier -- --write",
    "lint": "eslint --max-warnings 0 --fix --ext .js,.ts,.tsx .",
    "validate": "npm run format && npm run lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/raleway": "^0.1.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "5.9.7",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "3.0.3",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "1.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.8",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.3.14",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.3.14",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.19.0",
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.0.1",
    "expo-av": "~8.7.0",
    "expo-cli": "^4.3.2",
    "expo-file-system": "~9.3.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-media-library": "~10.0.0",
    "expo-permissions": "~10.0.0",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~2.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "expo-video-player": "^1.6.1",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.15.2",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-autoheight-webview": "^1.5.8",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^2.5.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.7.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.7.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.15.2",
    "react-native-sensitive-info": "^5.5.8",
    "react-native-shared-element": "0.7.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-native-webview": "11.0.0",
    "react-query": "^3.13.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.25.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.10.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run validate"
    }
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I just added the packake.json because it is only file i found relevant but tell me If another package needed.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `index.js`:

```
// index.js
global.Symbol = require('core-js/es6/symbol');
require('core-js/fn/symbol/iterator');
require('core-js/fn/map');
require('core-js/fn/set');
require('core-js/fn/array/find');
```

The way I see it is that there are certain JS syntaxes that doesn't translate well for android to understand.

Reference link: [Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15902#issuecomment-373964965)

Comment: Ref: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15902 
can you share your `index.js` file here? @yoann84